# How to find the available colours for hi-ColorColumn in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I need to set up a "colorcolumn" to indicate a length of 100 characters in vim (v7.4). Instead of using the default settings for "cterm", I would like to set a different colour.

Problem is, certain colour names I use, throw an error stating it is invalid.

```
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg=ivory guibg=blue
```

How can I find the list of available colours for my terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open vim and run the below command. It will list the available list of colours.

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/colortest.vim
```

I already have the below two lines added in my .vimrc file.

```
":set colorcolumn=100,80  (set multiple colorcolumn)   

:set cc=100                                                                                         
:hi ColorColumn ctermbg=lightcyan guibg=blue
```

For someone curious, I found useful information in the below documentation.

[Vim Documentation Syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight)

Comment: I will, thank you. Just that you know, StackOverflow will only allow the creator of the question to accept their own answer after two days. So I will need to wait till tomorrow.